# Does PHP support asynchronous calls?

Tags: php

I am planning to build a web application and am going to host it. Since hosting cost less for php and it being similar to .net i am planning to go for php.

I am basically a .net guy. But have no issues in learning php if it is similar to .net. Please give in your opinoins in doing so. Also please tell me if php supports asynchronous calls like the AJAX in asp.net. Give me your comments.

Comment: both asp.net and php runs on the web server. After that the similarities end imo. Don´t know if it´s because en is not your native language but AJAX is not a part of asp.net. I you mean Atlas (the implementation of ajax in asp.net) that´s fine. If web servers didn´t support asyncronous calls the web wouldn´t be a success: "loading cnn.com, please hold there are 20736 readers in que" =P

Comment: :-) I don't know about the web not being a success. Multiple connections to a web server (usually via threading) != A web page's ability to call asynchronously (usually via JavaScript) another page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous Javascript And XML**.  PHP isn't mentioned anywhere, and doesn't need to be asynchronous to facilitate this.

The process is that a Javascript function calls a synchronous PHP page that returns results and the users browser is updated.  The asycnhronous bit is that the javascript function doesn't block when it makes the call, and a callback function is fired when the PHP page returns.

I've implemented AJAX in PHP with no special programming above normal PHP HTML rendering and Javascript calls.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no built in support for asynchronous calls. You can make pseudo-asynchronous calls using [curl](https://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: Domain has expired on your link.

Answer (score 0):

If you plane to request MySQL, the MySQL driver bundled into PHP5.3 can make parallels queries. see the doc http://php.net/manual/mysqli.poll.php

You can also delegate tasks / emulate parallelism with [gearman](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gearman.php)